# How to set individual states to render components inside a map function in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component which has 3 radio buttons.Along with the radio buttons, I have an edit button which opens up a separate component when that particular edit button inside the radio button is clicked.But, the last radio button will not have the edit button inside the radio button. So,to render the edit component on click of the edit button, I have added state value inside my component as:

```
this.state = {
      isDrawerOpen: false,
      options: ['abc.sce.com', 'def.sce.com', 'No email alerts'],
}
```

So, I am rendering my radio buttons using a map function and below the radio button the new component should be called on the click of the edit button which is inside the radio button.

So, my code looks like below:

```
{this.state.options.map((email, i, arr) => {
          return (
           <RadioButtonComponent />   
                {!(arr[i].includes('No email alerts')) ? (
                  <button
                      id='editEmail'
                      onClick={this.handleEmailToggle} /> ) :
                  null}

               {this.state.isDrawerOpen ?  <OpenComponentOnEditClickOfRadiButton /> : null}

          );
```

My `handleEmailToggle()` function which is called on the edit button click is as follows:

```
  handleEmailToggle() {
    this.setState({ isDrawerOpen: true });
  }
```

So, when the edit button is clicked, the component `<OpenComponentOnEditClickOfRadiButton />` should open.Now what is happening is when I am clicking on any one of the edit button of the radio button,the component `<OpenComponentOnEditClickOfRadiButton />` is opening for all the radio buttons, even for the last radio button which doesn't have the edit button.So, how to set individual state for each edit button and render the new component only for that corresponding button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long ago, I faced the same issue as yours. I have done the following which did a trick:

```
const EditComp = () => <button type='button'>Edit</button>

class App extends Component {
    state = {
      isDrawerOpen: [],
      radioButton : [
        { id: "radio1", name: "male", edit: false,value: "male" },
        { id: "radio2", name: "female", edit: false, value: "female" }
      ],
      val: []
    };


  handleEmailToggle(event, currentIndex) {
    let showEdit = this.state.isDrawerOpen.map((val, index) => {
        return (val = false);
    }); 
    let isDrawerOpen = showEdit.slice();
    isDrawerOpen[currentIndex] = true;
    this.setState({ isDrawerOpen });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.radioButton.map((ele,index) => (
        <>
            <button key={ele.id} 
              onClick={e => this.handleEmailToggle(e, index)}>
            {ele.name} </button><br/>
            {this.state.isDrawerOpen[index] ? <EditComp /> : null}
            <br/>

        </>
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

what I did is, on each button click showed a edit button respectively.On every click current element index will be passed to the function and there's a state isDrawerOpen which stores each index with true/false respectively on particular element.

Hope  this helps to solve your query. [Code demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-foqdcs)

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot.It works. But could you please explain it once again. I am not able to get the function properly. Could you please elaborate once. Thanks a lot once again for your help :)

Comment: Also, 1 issue I am facing with this code is that on opening the new component on edit click, the component has a close button which also closes the component.So, if I close the component with the close button, and after that click on any of the edit buttons again, the edit buttons are not working.I guess  I need to pass the state to the next component right?But,I am not sure how to do it. So, could you please tell me how to solve this? If you want I can drop a separate question for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: While clicking close button, you should make isDrawerOpen[currentIndex] = false

Comment: Okay Jayavel,I will try it out.So, the function for the cancel click on the next component will be the same as the `handleEmailToggle()` function that you added here right ?

Comment: yes, you have to change state of respective index(element) as false through isDrawerOpen while close

Comment: okay, thanks a lot for your help. Will try it the way you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

you should try this:

```
{this.state.options.map((email, i, arr) => {
      return (
       <RadioButtonComponent />   
            {!(arr[i].includes('No email alerts')) ? (
              <button
                  id='editEmail'
                  onClick={e => this.handleEmailToggle(e, email)} /> ) :
              null}

           {this.state.isDrawerOpen ?  <OpenComponentOnEditClickOfRadiButton /> : null}

      );
```

and update your handleEmailToggle to:

```
handleEmailToggle(e, email) {
  // use email passed from map
  this.setState({ isDrawerOpen: true });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just give me few mins, I will try it out and let you know if its working.

Comment: great use of .includes()

Comment: @Howard, I tried your solution. I am still facing the same issue. One doubt that I have is what did you mean by `// use email passed from map` . Maybe I din't get your answer properly on how to change the function. Could please explain a little bit. I added the parameters on both the function and the onClick as you mentioned.